# WooCommerce Target Sub Product Categories

Tags: php, dynamic, woocommerce, conditional-statements, sidebar

I am sure one of you guys is smarter than me and can show me a solution for this. In WooCommerce I have product categories and sub categories for example:

**Shoes**

- Sneaker
- Derby
- Heels

**Clothes**

- Shirts
- Pullovers
- Jeans
- Trousers

I want to display a different sidebar for Each "set" of categories so for example I got a widget area (dynamic sidebar) for Shoes (including all it's sub cats Sneaker, Derby...) and I want to display the dynamic sidebar "shoes" for Clothes and (shirts, pullover...) I want to display the dynamic sidebar "clothes"... and so on.

so my first approach was listing all the categories with an conditional like this:

```
<?php if ( is_product_category( '25', '33', '34' )) { ?><?php dynamic_sidebar( 'shoes' ); ?><?php } ?>.....
```

problem with this is that subcategories get ignored by "is_product_category" and there is no sub_category conditional.

I would be ok with just finding a conditional that is also recognizing sub categories... but the perfect solution I am looking for is some automated way to either have a conditional or include a custom sidebar for a category and all it's sub categories so I don't have to list them all ID by ID and as son as I add a new child to a parent it also gets appended so the sidebar is based on the parent...

If someone of you knows a solution I would be super happy, I messed around with this for days and didn't find a solution.